# PrimeFaces dataTable: strange ELException caused by ClassCastException (no stacktrace) using GlassFish + Mojarra

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish, el

We have a list of collision entities that you can single-select in a PrimeFaces `<p:datatable>`. Below that one is a fieldset which shows the associated history and file attachments.

Here's the JSF page (the attachments datatable is more important than the rest):

```
<h:panelGrid>

    <p:scrollPanel mode="native">
        <p:dataTable value="#{collisionManager.selectedCollisions}"
                     var="cln"
                     selection="#{collisionManager.selectedStateChangeCollision}" 
                     selectionMode="single"
                     rowKey="#{cln.id}"
                     paginator="true"
                     paginatorPosition="bottom"
                     rows="5">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" process="@this" update="@form" />

            <p:column headerText="ID">
                <h:outputText value="#{cln.id}" />
            </p:column>

            ...

        </p:dataTable>
    </p:scrollPanel>

    <p:fieldset legend="History and Attachments">

        <p:tabView widgetVar="stateChangeTabView"
                   dynamic="true"
                   cache="false">

            <p:tab title="History">
                ...
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab title="Attachments">
                <p:dataTable id="attachments-datatable"
                             value="#{attachmentManager.activeAttachments}"
                             var="att"
                             paginator="true"
                             paginatorPosition="bottom"
                             rows="3">

                    <p:column headerText="File Name">
                        <h:outputText value="#{att.fileName}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Deleted">
                        <h:outputText value="#{att.deleted}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Marked">
                        <h:outputText value="#{attachmentManager.markedToDelete(att)}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Actions">
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"
                                         title="Mark to delete"
                                         action="#{attachmentManager.markToDelete(att)}"
                                         process="@this"
                                         update="@form"
                                         rendered="#{not attachmentManager.markedToDelete(att)}">
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon ui-icon-cancel"
                                         title="Unmark to delete"
                                         action="#{attachmentManager.unmarkToDelete(att)}"
                                         process="@this"
                                         update="@form"
                                         rendered="#{not attachmentManager.markedToDelete(att)}">
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:tab>

        </p:tabView>

    </p:fieldset>

</h:panelGrid>

<!-- SAVE + CANCEL buttons here -->
```

Here's the `AttachmentManager` bean (there's Seam 3 Faces on the classpath for `@Named` and `@Viewscoped` to be compatible, shouldn't matter here):

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class AttachmentManager implements Serializable
{
    // attachments to be deleted
    private List<Attachment> markedAttachments;

    public void markToDelete( Attachment attachment )
    {
        if ( !this.markedAttachments.contains( attachment ) )
        {
            this.markedAttachments.add( attachment );
        }
    }

    public void unmarkToDelete( Attachment attachment )
    {
        this.markedAttachments.remove( attachment );
    }

    public boolean markedToDelete( Attachment attachment )
    {
        return this.markedAttachments.contains( attachment );
    }
}
```

The problems start when evaluating the expression in the page on the line (attachments table):

```
<h:outputText value="#{attachmentManager.markedToDelete(att)}" />
```

It doesn't matter which expression in the code above is actually executed, they basically all fail with:

```
javax.el.ELException: /view/changeData.xhtml @184,102 value="#{not attachmentManager.markedToDelete(att)}": java.lang.ClassCastException: com.company.project.model.Attachment cannot be cast to com.company.project.model.Collision
```

Note, that there's absolutely no stacktrace - at least not that I was able to find one. I even looked into the server response (AJAX) where we noticed some exceptions sometimes getting swallowed - nothing.

I found two other posts related to my problem (unsolved, too):

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4270

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5923

**Q:**
Does anybody know what could be wrong about the EL expression `#{not attachmentManager.markedToDelete(att)}`?

*Q2:*
Where could the stacktrace be gone or more specifically, how/where do I find it?

The environment we're in is: GlassFish 3.1.2.2, Mojarra 2.1.6, PrimeFaces 3.4

Comment: Interesting. What if you replace the argument type `Attacument` by `Object`? Then put a debug breakpoint on the 1st line to see what was really been passed and explore the call stack who did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exchanged the server's Mojarra with version 2.1.14 and after a few reloads/retries the stacktrace finally appeared. (on the first few tries it was all the same, maybe GlassFish caches relevant parts of its JARs)

After that it was as easy as it could have been: I had copied the equals method from `Collision` to `Attachment` and left a cast to `Collision` unchanged. That's what caused the CCE.

However, it's still a mystery where the stacktrace was going...